# Each character own element

Tags: regex, r, strsplit

I have a character vector

```
x <- "nkiLVkqspmLVAydnaVNLSCkys"
```

I want to split it into a vector with 25 elements, so that:

```
x[1] 
# [1] "n"
x[2] 
# [1] "k"
# and so on ...
```

The only thing I can think of is to do a `regex` replace any alpha character with alpha and `","` and then split on `","`. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand what you are suggestion Dason? strsplit on my list would just give me a vector with a single element that has all the letters. That is what I am starting with. I understand that if I modify my original string to include commas I can then split on the commas with strsplit. I was asking if there is another way to do this.

Comment: can you please put me out of my misery and tell me HOW to use strsplit in this case?

Comment: Dason - please see below answer for example on how to be helpful to newbies.

Comment: @user2909302 he helped you. Please dont be rude. You should have asked him directly to spoon feed you.

Comment: What @Dason was attempting to do was to help you find `example(strsplit)` (also at the bottom of `?strsplit`). There is an example there of exactly what you are attempting to do. i.e RTFM

Comment: I did not mean to be rude but since i mentioned strsplit in my question i dont see how telling me to look at strsplit could be construed as helping me.

Comment: @RichardScriven Not even that necessary. It's spelled out if you read the info for the split parameter.  So user2909302 did you actually read the documentation?  I mean I reiterated it twice so you know... I would hope you would have got the hint and actually read it.

Comment: @user2909302 Not being spoon fed a simple answer when the answer is in the documentation is a skill that will help you much more in the long run than getting the immediate answer.  I do you a much greater service if I attempt to help you learn how to learn than if I just give you the direct answer. And if you put any effort in you would have got the answer from my hint. I'm not trying to be rude.

Comment: @Dason, you are correct, it is much better to gain the skill of effectively using the documentation. I was looking for a quick answer and should have specified that. I interpreted your answer as aggressive only because you wrote the same response twice. To a frustrated newbie who has spent hours trying to untangle data frames in R the spoonfed answer was the easiest to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
x<-"nkiLVkqspmLVAydnaVNLSCkys"
y<-data.frame(strsplit(x,""))
```

then do:

```
y[1,1]
```

or

```
y[2,1]
```

and so on ...

Comment: `unlist(strsplit(x,""))` would give exactly the desired result.

Comment: @RichardScriven thank you, that is actually a simpler output format for me and I'll use unlist instead of data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use

```
library(stringr)
y= data.frame(v1=str_extract_all(x, '.')[[1]])
```